# Windows 8 can't override Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, secure-boot

I had Windows 8 installed on my Asus X5551M, then I installed Ubuntu 14.04 over it. Now I want to go back to Windows 8 to sell the computer.

I created a Windows 8 USB using the exe from the Windows site and used that USB in the laptop. But when I try to override I get a red box with "Secure Boot Violation" Invalid signature detected. Check Boot Policy in Setup.

When I turn off Secure Boot, it just goes straight to Ubuntu. Any idea why this is happening?